# Class Diagram not supported asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

When I create class diagram shown the below message and I saw many resolution in this site, and all answer about code string, but I don't know where I import this code in my project, so you advise here will be highly appreciated.

This code I don't know how I can use it and where :-

```
  string uriPath =
"file:\\E:\The Last\WebSite_x\ClassDiagram.cd";
    string localPath = new Uri(uriPath).LocalPath;
```

[image: ERROR]

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). You want X. You thought if you created a file URI you'd get X. You tried to create one but didn't get X. We can't help until you explain what X is. Show us the code that throws this error because what you have shown us doesn't.

Comment: in visual studio "web Application" ,  i select i above bar "WEBSITE" then 'Add New Item'.
then i chose class diagram and after that the class diagram shown in the solution explorer bar and when i double click into class diagram show this massage error in the body question.